# Variable Corruption C++ String Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, string, variables, visual-studio-2005, memory-corruption

I have following code in my project.

```
g(const string& str)
{
    printf("%s", str.c_str());
}  

f()
{
    string str("whatever");

    g(str);
}
```

It is part of very large code. g() is in a dll and api is exported. f() is part of an executable. This code used to work fine. But now it only works in debug configuration and not in release configuration. I tried to debug and found that as soon as I hit first statement of g() str contents just evaporate. So it prints null.

The release configuration has not changed.

Please help.

Best regards,
Shiv

Comment: Voting to close: You should try to reduce the original piece of code until you realize what is failing. The question as it is cannot be answered, as the posted code does not exhibit the behavior. The answer is that there is something wrong somewhere in your code, but that is hardly constructive. Note (this might be the problem) that if you compile with different flags the main program and the dll the definitions of the STL might be different, and that will cause a violation of the ODR and undefined behavior.

Comment: This sounds like a build problem (probably having to do with the linker). My advice: (1) do a clean rebuild; (2) make sure that BOTH the DLL and the main program are built in release mode; (3) make sure you always pick up the correct DLL when running the main program; (4) even though you say that the release configuration hasn't changed, double-check that this is in fact true.

Answer (score 2):

Wild shot in the dark:

You have compiled the DLL and the program with different compiler flags, and in the difference the implementation of the STL is different (maybe you are using checked iterators in one but not the other...). That is a violation of the ODR and will cause undefined behavior.

Basically one end will create it's version of the object, and pass a reference to the other end, but the other end will try to interpret the memory in a different way.

If that is the case, you should be able to determine that the address of the string in the caller and callee are the same, and that the memory in that address has the same bit pattern it as much as `sizeof(std::string)` in the calling code. If that is the case, and both ends are interpreting the string differently you have an ODR violation. Recompile all the project with the same exact compiler flags.

Another hint that there are two definitions is if the value of `sizeof(std::string)` differs in the main program and the DLL (or in different DLLs). If the sizes differ, that tells you that there is a ODR violation. The sizes being the same cannot be used to assert that the ODR has not been violated: they might be different definitions with the same size.

Comment: This is likely. Note that one can use the Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see which runtime the different DLLs are using. (Doens't work with statically linked stuff though.)